# discordjs можно ли получить список всех людей которые нажали на реакцию?

Tags: node.js, discord

discordjs можно ли получить список всех людей которые нажали на реакцию?

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription("Викторина скоро начнется. Для участия нажмите на ✅");
    mess.channel.send(embed).then((msg) =>{
        msg.react("✅");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам необходимо любым образом получить сообщение с реакциями.

```
// Если реакция только одна:
cosnt users = message.reactions.cache.first().users

// Иначе
const users = message.reactions.cache.find(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === `✅`).users
```